# Bounding the norms of the powers of a $2\times 2$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, matrix-norms, spectral-radius

Let $\|.\|_2$ denote the matrix norm induced from the Euclidian vectornorm and let

\begin{align}
M=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
a+b & -b \\
1 & 0
\end{array}\right).
\end{align}
I need to bound $\|M^n\|_2$ for any $n\in \mathbb{N}$. It is assumed that $a\in[0,1]$ and $b\in(0,1)$. I tried to use Gelfand's formula from which we obtain:
$$\|M^n\|_2\leq (\rho(M)+o(1))^n,$$
where $\rho(M)$ denotes the spectral radius of $M$. It is easy to see why $\rho(M)\leq \max\left\{1-\frac{1-a}{2},b\right\}$. Therefore  $\|M^n\|_2<c$ for any n, if   $\, a\leq q<1$.
In the case $a=1$ we see that:
\begin{align*}
\|M^n\|_2=\left\|\frac{1}{b-1}\left(\begin{array}{cc}
b^{n+1}-1 & -b-b^{n+1} \\
b^{n}-1 & -b-b^{n}
\end{array}\right)\right\|_2\leq c.
\end{align*}
But I have no idea how to bound $\|M^n\|_2$ when $a \rightarrow 1$, since I haven't found any results on the convergence of Gelfand's formula. Any suggestions how to prove this?
Also according to many plots, it should hold that

\begin{align*}
\|M^n\|_2\leq\left\|\frac{1}{b-1}\left(\begin{array}{cc}
b^{n+1}-1 & -b-b^{n+1} \\
b^{n}-1 & -b-b^{n}
\end{array}\right)\right\|_2\leq c,
\end{align*}
for any $a\in[0,1]$. Any idea how to prove the last inequality?

Comment: It is a bit strange to have "a_n" as a parameter in the matrix $M$ and then consider its $n$-th power. Wouldn't it be better to call the parameter simply "a"?

Comment: Well maybe, but in case where a is fixed, i can differ between the two cases as mentioned. The only problem that can occure, is when a converges to 1 in the first case. So to make clear that this case might be possible i indexed a with n.

Comment: 1. It is still better to use simp ly "a" as a parameter. "$a_n$" is confusing here. 2. The problem is interesting because there can be no bound independent of $b$. If such a bound existed then it woud be valid also for $a=b=1$, but here $M^n=nM-(n-1)I$ has norm of order $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I show that there is a constant $K>0$ such that for all $a\in[0,1]$, $b\in]0,1[$ and all positive integers $n$ we have
$$\tag{1}||M^n||_2\leq\frac K{1-b} \mbox{ for }M=\begin{pmatrix}a+b&-b\\1&0\end{pmatrix}.$$
As a numerical value for $K$, we obtain $K=2$.

Observe that there cannot exist a constant $L$ such that $||M^n||_2\leq L$
for all the above $a,b,n$. If such an $L$ existed we would have
$||M^n||_2\leq L$ also for $a=b=1$ by continuity, that is for $M=\begin{pmatrix}2&-1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}.$ Now this matrix has a double eigenvalue $\lambda=1$ and $M=I+N$ with the nilpotent matrix
$N=\begin{pmatrix}1&-1\\1&-1\end{pmatrix}.$ Hence
$M^n=I+nN$ for all $n$ and $||M^n||_2$ is unbounded.

It would be simpler to show for each $(a,b)$ that either both eigenvalues of $M$ are inside the open unit disk or that both are inside the closed unit disk and different and then to conclude boundedness of $||M^n||_2$ in each case. The eigenvalues are also discussed in the proof below. The aim of the proof is to find
the best possible type of bound valid for all $a,b$ considered in the question.

Proof of (1): The characteristic polynomial of $M$ is $p(x)=x^2-(a+b)x+b$.
Therefore $M^2=(a+b)M-bI$ and hence $M^{n+1}=(a+b)M^n-bM^{n-1}$ for all $n$.
Hence there exist sequences $c_n,d_n$ such that
$M^n=c_n M+d_nI$ for all $n$ and $c_{n+1}=(a+b)c_n-bc_{n-1}$,
$d_{n+1}=(a+b)d_n-bd_{n-1}$. We also have $M^{n+1}=M\,M^n=((a+b)c_n+d_n)M-bc_nI$ and hence $d_n=-bc_{n-1}$. We have shown that
$$\tag{2}M^n=c_nM-bc_{n-1}I \mbox{ where } c_{n+1}=(a+b)c_n-bc_{n-1} 
\mbox{ and }c_0=0,c_1=1.$$

So it suffices to show that there is a constant $K$  such that
$|c_n|\leq K/(1-b)$ for all $a\in[0,1]$, $b\in]0,1[$ and all positive integers $n$.

The sequences $\{x_n\}_n$ satisfying
$$\tag3 x_{n+1}=(a+b)x_n-bx_n$$
form a vector space of dimension two. If $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ are the roots
of $p(x)$, i.e. $\lambda_j^2=(a+b)\lambda_j-b$ then we can give a basis of this vector space.
If the roots are different, then $\{\lambda_j^n\}_n$, $j=1,2$ form a basis;
if there is a double root then $\{\lambda_1^n\}_n$ and $\{n\lambda_1^n\}_n$
form a basis.$\newcommand{\l}{\lambda}$

Case 1: $p$ has a double root $\l$. Then $\l=\sqrt b$ and $a+b=2\l=2\sqrt b$.
Hence $a=2\sqrt b-b\in]0,1[$ because $0<b<1$. Using the initial conditions, we find that $c_n=n\l^{n-1}$ for all $n$. We show
$$\tag4 n\l^{n-1}\leq\frac1{1-\l}\mbox{ for all positive }n\mbox{ and }\l\in[0,1[.$$
Indeed, the function $f(\l)=n\l^{n-1}(1-\l)$ assumes its maximum in $\l=\frac{n-1}n$ and this maximum is $\left(\frac{n-1}n\right)^{n-1}$.
As
$$\frac1{1-\sqrt b}=\frac{1+\sqrt b}{1-b}\leq \frac2{1-b}$$
(2) and (4) prove the statement in this case.

Case 2: $\l_1\neq\l_2$. Here we find from the initial conditions that
$$\tag5 c_n=\frac{\l_1^n-\l_2^n}{\l_1-\l_2}=\l_1^{n-1}+\l_1^{n-2}\l_2+\cdots+\l_2^{n-1}.$$
If both roots are complex conjugates, then we have $|\l_1|=|\l_2|=\sqrt b$ because $|\l_1|^2=\l_1\overline{\l_1}=\l_1\l_2=b$. Hence
$|c_n|\leq n\sqrt b^{n-1}$ and we conclude as in case 1 that
$|c_n|\leq\frac2{1-b}$.

It remains to treat the case of two different real roots. As $\l_1+\l_2=a+b>0$ and $\l_1\l_2=b>0$, both are positive.
Since $p(1)=1-a\geq0$ and $p'(x)=2x-a-b>0$ for all $x\geq1$
both roots are in $]0,1]$. We assume $0<\l_1<\l_2\leq1$. Observe that
$\l_2=1$ if $a=1$.

We also have $$\l_1=\frac{a+b}2-\sqrt{\left(\frac{a+b}2\right)^2-b}$$
and hence $1-\l_1\geq1-\frac{a+b}2\geq\frac{1-b}2$.
Since their sum equals $1-\l_1$, we have $\l_2-\l_1\geq\frac{1-b}4$
or $1-\l_2\geq\frac{1-b}4$.

In the first case, $|c_n|\leq\frac1{\lambda_2-\l_1}\leq\frac4{1-b}$.

In the second case, we have $|c_n|\leq n\l_2^{n-1}$ and using  (4), we obtain $|c_n|\leq \frac 4{1-b}$. This completes the proof.

Remarks: In all the cases, we find that $|c_n|\leq\frac4{1-b}$ for all $n$ and hence by (2), we find that (1) holds with
$K=4(\sup_{a,b}||M||_2+1)=4(2+\sqrt2)\approx13.66$.

The estimates of the above proof can actually be sharpened. At the same time, the second question will be answered.
Observe first that (2) also implies that
$$\tag6 M^n=\begin {pmatrix}c_{n+1}&-bc_{n}\\
             c_n&-bc_{n-1}\end{pmatrix}.$$
This can also be proved by induction using the recursion for the sequence $\{c_n\}_n$. In the special case $a=1$, (5) implies
$$M^n=\frac1{1-b}\begin {pmatrix}1-b^{n+1}&-b+b^{n+1}\\
             1-b^n&-b+b^n\end{pmatrix}.$$
Except for two signs, this is a formula mentioned in the question.

Later we show that
$$\tag7|c_n|\leq\frac{1-b^n}{1-b}\mbox{ for all }a\in[0,1],b\in]0,1[\mbox{ and nonnegative integers }n. $$
Now the definition of the $\|.\|_2$-norm for matrices shows that
$$\tag8\left\|\begin {pmatrix}u_{1}&u_{2}\\
             u_3&u_{4}\end{pmatrix}\right\|_2\leq
\left\|\begin {pmatrix}v_{1}&v_{2}\\
             v_3&v_{4}\end{pmatrix}\right\|_2$$
if $|u_i|\leq v_i$ for $i=1,2,3,$. Hence (6) and (7) imply that
$$\|M^n\|_2\leq
\left\|\frac1{1-b}\begin {pmatrix}1-b^{n+1}&b-b^{n+1}\\
             1-b^n&b-b^n\end{pmatrix}\right\|_2.$$
This answers the second question and corrects a sign error in it.
Furthermore since $1-b^n\leq1$ etc, we obtain with (8)
$$\|M^n\|_2\leq\frac1{1-b}\left\|\begin {pmatrix}{1}&{1}\\
             1&{1}\end{pmatrix}\right\|_2\leq\frac2{1-b}.$$

It remains to prove (7). Here we use formula (5),the second part of which is valid also if $x^2-(a+b)x+b$ has a double root.

Case 1: $x^2-(a+b)x+b$ has two complex comjugate roots $\l_1,\l_2$ or a double root $\l_1=\l_2$. Using $|\l_1|=|\l_2|=\sqrt b$,
we find that
$$|c_n|\leq n\,b^{(n-1)/2}\leq 1+b+\cdots + b^{n-1}=\frac{1-b^n}{1-b}.$$
Here we used that $2\,b^{(n-1)/2}\leq b^i+b^{n-1-i}$ for $0\leq i<\frac12(n-1)$ and added all these inequalities and a single middle term in the case of odd $n$.

Case 2: $x^2-(a+b)x+b$ has two different real roots $\l_1,\l_2$.
Recall that $b=\l_1\l_2$ and that we can assume that
$0<\l_1<\l_2\leq1$. For convenience, we treat only even $n=2m$, the modifications for odd $n$ are left to the reader. Using (5), it is sufficient to show that
$$\tag9 \l_2^{n-1}+b\l_2^{n-3}+\cdots+b^{n-2}\l_2^{-n+3}+b^{n-1}\l_2^{-n+1}\leq1+b+\cdots+b^{n-2}+b^{n-1}$$
if $\sqrt b<\l_2\leq1$. This in turn follows from the fact that
for any nonnegative integer $k\leq m-1$, the function
$g:]\sqrt b,1]\to\mathbb R$,
$g(x)=b^{k}x^{n-1-2k}+b^{n-1-k}x^{2k-n+1}$, has a positive derivative. Therefore it is strictly increasing and hence $g(\l_2)\leq g(1)$ for $\l_2\in]\sqrt b,1]$.

Comment: @MN. I am glad you like my answer. I have just added some improved estimates and also answered your second question.

Comment: Thank you very much again for your solution and your time! Your answer is awesome :)

Comment: @MN. Thanks! I saw that you really like my answer:-)

Comment: @MN. Do not worry about reputation points. I could feel how much you like my answer! Still, you are invited to learn from some other of my answers that are interesting for you.